# lowering volume of the ringtone when I pick up my phone

Tags: audio, functionality

I'm sure if this was a brain fart or a feature of the phone. I got HTC Thropy updated to 7.5 and I noticed when the phone rings and I pick up my phone from the desk it lowers its volume. It sounds like a nice feature. Using accelerometer phone recognize that I noticed the incoming call, so what is the point or ringing after?

Is this a feature?

Comment: The point of carrying on ringing is that you might want to ignore/reject the call

Comment: after I pick up the phone and see the screen "xyz calling" there's no point to keep carrying on ringing. I can press ignore. I wonder, though, how this feature would work in a bit different environment e.g. ship.

Answer (score 5):

This is likely behavior of the HTC Attentive Phone app. It allows for settings to quiet on pickup, pocket mode, flip for speaker, and flip to silence.

[image: Attentive Phone Settings]

Link to summary of features: http://www.wpcentral.com/new-htc-attentive-phone-integrates-settings-available-mango

Comment: I don't have this app and options in settings.

Comment: Lukas you can download it from the htc section in the marketplace